# How to mock API for debugging my code

Tags: javascript, debugging, mocking

My application is written in javascript and interacts with a fairly complex javascript API. This API makes HTTP GET ajax requests to the server which responds with JSON output.
I'm in the process of debugging my application and I'm wasting loads of time to replicate a specific scenario because I need to populate the server with new data every time I want to run that scenario.

What would be the best way to mock the responses from the API so that I can keep recreating the same scenario over and over without having to regenerate test data on the server? Is there any product that you would suggest?

Comment: It depends entirely on the complication involved in the API.  If it's just a single GET request that returns some JSON data, you can literally create a page of JSON and put it on any web server somewhere (like in your dropbox account) and then modify the URL in your app to pull that page instead.  This will return the JSON you want your app to receive.  Or, you can stub out the request in your app and just hardwire the desired JSON.  Or, you could build a dummy server in node.js that responds to the same API with the desired data.

Comment: If you show more about what API requests you're trying to simulate, you will likely get much more meaningful and targeted answers.

Comment: I cannot share too much information about this API because it's proprietary, but the typical response involves a javascript object with several properties that represent the state of the application. Ideally i'd like to "record" the server responses and replay them back over and over

Comment: Save the API JSON respones to a file and then temporarily hardwire them in somewhere by any of the methods I outlined above.

Comment: I'll give a try to it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Service Virtualization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_virtualization) technique for the purpose. Using this you can record the call and later mock it.

- The recording step sets up an HTTP Proxy, to give you an opportunity to record the request and response.
- Once you have a sample response, you can edit the JSON, and add more objects to suit your use-case.

There are many tools and frameworks for service virtualization. Please do your research.